# Displaying a webpage and maps in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to know how to display a webpage of a predefined URL in Blackberry. I would also like to get help in displaying map of a predefined location on a button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

displaying a web page is straightforward:

```
public static void navigateToSite(final String url) {  
    BrowserSession session = Browser.getDefaultSession();  
    session.displayPage(url);  
}
```

and for the location, check http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11944/CS_invoking_BB_Maps_using_a_Landmark_887800_11.jsp

Comment: not sure what more you looking for..? the code above is a working "sample" and the BB documentation as well works (ie. i have recently used it and it works)